# Javascript: How to convert array ["a=1", "b=2"] into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, type-conversion

What is the best way to convert:

```
user = ['Name:Marry', 'Age:24', 'Gender:Female']
```

to

```
user = { 'Name':'Marry', 'Age':'24', 'Gender':'Female' }
```

Comment: Loop through the array. Use `split()` to split it into two parts at the `:`. Then use the first part as the key and the second part as the value of the property.

Comment: Please try: `console.log(['Name:Marry', 'Age:24', 'Gender:Female'].reduce((o, s) => { const [k, v] = s.split(':'); o[k]=v; return o; }, {}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you want to convert an array to a single value( here it is an object ), for this more declarative way is to use reduce method. Here I have given an empty object as the initial value of the accumulator and on each iteration it adds the key value pair.

```
const result = user.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [key, value] = curr.split(':');
  acc[key] = value;
  
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
const result = Object.assign({}, ...user.map(item => item.split(':')).map(item => ({ [item[0]]: item[1]})))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    user = ['Name:Marry', 'Age:24', 'Gender:Female']
    const userObj = {}

    for(item of user) {
      const [key, value] = item.split(":")
      userObj[key] = value
    }
    
    console.log(userObj)
```